# Conditional Formatting consistency in modified Tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

**QUESTION:**

how can I keep conditional formatting consistent and easy to manage in a table (ListObject) that is constantly sorted, filtered, and modified by adding new rows (either manually or via VBA).

**DETAILS**

I can get a range of cells formatted just the way I want, but find I wind up with 'stray' items in the Conditional Format Manager.

For example, the 3rd row in the image below shows the correct Apply To Range, as the table is current spanning rows 6 through 268 (I just cleaned it up by hand). But I wind up with problems:

1. Orphaned line items with a single AppliesToRange, as in the 1st row
2. Orphaned line items with a blank AppliesToRange, as in the 2nd row
3. Out of sequence Applies to Range. What I mean my this is I wind up with something like "=$BA$17,$BA$6:$BA$16,etc." instead of the easy to understand at a glance "=$BA$6:$BA$268"

[image]

For completeness, here is the formula for this particular format:
[image]

And here is a different formula that us based on a reference. In this one I have to column constant and the row relative, as I want it to apply to all rows in the table. Not sure if this is the right way to do it.

[image]

So what is the best way to set up and manage my formats in this table?